# How to delete multiple file same extension but keep newest one

Tags: linux, bash, file, delete-file

I want to delete *.zip or *.log files but keep last created one(newest).

For example:

```
text-ids.zip(12.10.2013)
text-ids.zip(13.10.2013)
..
.
text-ids.zip(19.10.2013) <-- keep this one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -ct *.zip | tail -n +2 | xargs rm
```

- `ls -ct` show files, sorted by ctime
- `tail -n +2` remove first line
- `xargs rm` call `rm` on the remaining